# (other question doesnt answer my second error found in comment )trying to make code that will mix two photos together by 1 pixel at a time

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image


def main():
    # get photo 1
     image1 = Image.open(
         "/Users/whickey27/Pictures/Photo Booth Library/Pictures/Photo on 10-16-23 at 11.38       AM.jpg")

     # get photo2
     image2 = Image.open(
          "/Users/whickey27/Pictures/Photo Booth Library/Pictures/Photo on 10-16-23 at 11.39 AM.jpg")

      # turn photo one into an array
      array1 = np.asarray(image1)

     # Turn photo two into an array
     array2 = np.asarray(image2)

     final_product = array1

     for i in range(0, len(array1[0]), 2):
        final_product[i] = array2[i]

     # Make image from finall_product
     Image.fromarray(final_product).save("my.img.numpy.png")



main()
```

whenever I run this I get this error

final_product[i] = array2[i]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
ValueError: assignment destination is read-only

if you could help that would be great

FYI
1.Im new to python and numpy and PIL

Comment: Does changing `final_product = array1` to `final_product = np.copy(array1)` work?

Comment: Use `np.array(XXX)` rather than `np.asarray(XXX)`

Comment: @MarkSetchell     I tried you comment and ended up with the error                 
index 960 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 960

Comment: @Joe when I changed this it game me the error.                                                                                                     index 960 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 960

Comment: Use `len(xxx)-1` so you don't run off the end.

Comment: This isn't going to work unless both images are the same size.

Comment: do you know how to make it so it still works if images are different sizes?

Comment: Yes. Either resize one to match the other's size, or restrict your processing to pixels contained within the smaller of the two.